What packages are required for functionality with `latex` output for `modelsummary`?
Love the modelsummary package, but since updating to the latest version, I can't even get the simplest possible regression table to compile without errors in Overleaf.
Consider the following R code:
library("groundhog") # for temporal reproducibility
meta.groundhog(date = "2024-04-30")
groundhog.library("modelsummary", date = "2024-04-30")

set.seed(05232024) # for result reproducibility

x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x*2 + rnorm(100)

fit <- lm(y ~ x)

modelsummary(fit, output = "latex")

which produces the following LaTeX code:
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}[         %% tabularray outer open
]                     %% tabularray outer close
{                     %% tabularray inner open
colspec={Q[]Q[]},
column{1}={halign=l,},
column{2}={halign=c,},
hline{6}={1,2}{solid, 0.05em, black},
}                     %% tabularray inner close
\toprule
& (1) \\ \midrule %% TinyTableHeader
(Intercept) & 0.010    \\
& (0.093)  \\
x           & 1.868    \\
& (0.086)  \\
Num.Obs.    & 100      \\
R2          & 0.827    \\
R2 Adj.     & 0.825    \\
AIC         & 272.5    \\
BIC         & 280.3    \\
Log.Lik.    & -133.254 \\
F           & 468.067  \\
RMSE        & 0.92     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table} 

If I put this into a text editor with a TeX installation (or Overleaf, I've tried in several different ways), I always get errors. I use \usepackage{tabularray} and \usepackage{booktabs}. By my reading, it's not clear that I need other packages but perhaps I'm missing something? I've tried to update my TeX installation, used Overleaf, etc.
Overleaf error message:
<argument> \color 
                  {\l__tblr_f_tl }
l.42 \end
         {tblr}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to return to the old modelsummary output?
The only other thing I can think of is that modelsummary returns this message when loading:
`modelsummary` 2.0.0 now uses `tinytable` as its default table-drawing
  backend. Learn more at: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/tinytable/

Revert to `kableExtra` for one session:

  options(modelsummary_factory_default = 'kableExtra')

but I don't think this is the issue because I've tried to revert to kableExtra with the same results.

If you knit to a pdf you might observe the following included:
## Warning: To compile a LaTeX document with this table, the following commands must be placed in the document preamble:
## 
## \usepackage{tabularray}
## \usepackage{float}
## \usepackage{graphicx}
## \usepackage{codehigh}
## \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
## \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
## \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
## \newcommand{\tinytableTabularrayUnderline}[1]{\underline{#1}}
## \newcommand{\tinytableTabularrayStrikeout}[1]{\sout{#1}}
## \NewTableCommand{\tinytableDefineColor}[3]{\definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}}
## 
## To disable `siunitx` and prevent `modelsummary` from wrapping numeric entries in `\num{}`, call:
## 
## options("modelsummary_format_numeric_latex" = "plain")
##  This warning appears once per session.

Therefore, your Overleaf could look something like this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{codehigh}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\newcommand{\tinytableTabularrayUnderline}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\newcommand{\tinytableTabularrayStrikeout}[1]{\sout{#1}}
\NewTableCommand{\tinytableDefineColor}[3]{\definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}[         %% tabularray outer open
]                     %% tabularray outer close
{                     %% tabularray inner open
colspec={Q[]Q[]},
column{1}={halign=l,},
column{2}={halign=c,},
hline{6}={1,2}{solid, 0.05em, black},
}                     %% tabularray inner close
\toprule
& (1) \\ \midrule %% TinyTableHeader
(Intercept) & 0.010    \\
& (0.093)  \\
x           & 1.868    \\
& (0.086)  \\
Num.Obs.    & 100      \\
R2          & 0.827    \\
R2 Adj.     & 0.825    \\
AIC         & 272.5    \\
BIC         & 280.3    \\
Log.Lik.    & -133.254 \\
F           & 468.067  \\
RMSE        & 0.92     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table} 

\end{document}



Thanks very much, it's a smart idea to knit that I didn't think of.
